# Where am I wrong here? The lookup for the name Node finds the injected-class-name for the struct Node

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, lookup, c++14

I'm in doubt about the first comment in the Example at §3.4.4/3 (C++14):

```
struct Node {
    struct Node* Next; // OK: Refers to Node at global scope
    struct Data* Data; // OK: Declares type Data
                       // at global scope and member Data
};
```

From §3.3.2/7 (see below), one concludes that the comment is correct, because the global namespace is the smallest namespace containing the declaration `struct Node* Next;`.

§3.3.2/7 (my emphasis)

> The point of declaration of a class first declared in an
>   elaborated-type-specifier is as follows:
>
> - for a declaration of the form
>
>   *class-key attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> identifier* ;
>
>   the identifier is declared to be a *class-name* in the scope that
>     contains the declaration, otherwise
> - for an *elaborated-type-specifier* of the form
>
>   *class-key identifier*
>
>   if the *elaborated-type-specifier* is used in the *decl-specifier-seq* or *parameter-declaration-clause* of a function defined in namespace scope, the *identifier* is declared as a
>     *class-name* in the namespace that contains the declaration; **otherwise**, except as a friend declaration, **the *identifier* is declared in the smallest namespace or block scope that contains the
>     declaration**. [ Note: These rules also apply within templates. —end
>     note ] [ Note: Other forms of *elaborated-type-specifier* do not
>     declare a new name, and therefore must refer to an existing
>     *type-name*. See 3.4.4 and 7.1.6.3. —end note ]

However from §3.4.4/2 (see below) I get the impression that the lookup for the name `Node` finds the injected-class-name `Node`, so it can't refer to `Node` in the global scope.

§3.4.4/2 (my emphasis)

> If the *elaborated-type-specifier* has no *nested-name-specifier*, and
>   unless the *elaborated-type-specifier* appears in a declaration with
>   the following form:
>
> *class-key attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> identifier* ;
>
> **the *identifier* is looked up according to 3.4.1 but ignoring any non-type names that have been declared**. If the
>   *elaborated-type-specifier* is introduced by the enum keyword and this lookup does not find a previously declared *type-name*, the
>   *elaborated-type-specifier* is ill-formed. If the *elaborated-type-specifier* is introduced by the *class-key* and this lookup does not find a previously declared *type-name*, or if the
>   *elaborated-type-specifier* appears in a declaration with the form:
>
> *class-key attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> identifier* ;
>
> the *elaborated-type-specifier* is a declaration that introduces the
>   *class-name* as described in 3.3.2.

Comment: 3.3.2/7 doesn't apply because Node is not first declared in the elaborated-type-specifier. Yes, the lookup should find the injected class name.

Comment: Are you sure about this? Not that I'm doubting what you said. I'm just surprised with my intuition. Anyway, that was a heck of a good answer. Why don't you fill out an answer, so that I can close the thread. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sentence of [basic.scope.pdecl]/7 makes clear that that paragraph deals with **a class first declared in an *elaborated-type-specifier***; it is therefore not applicable to the `struct Node` in `struct Node* Next;`, because `Node` is not first declared in that *elaborated-type-specifier*.

Instead, the unqualified name lookup for `Node` does find the *injected-class-name* (see [basic.lookup.unqual]/p1 and 7.1) rather than `::Node`. You'll need to write some rather contrived code for this to matter, though. For example:

```
struct A {};
struct B : private A {};
struct C : public B {
    struct A m_a; // error: A is the inaccessible injected-class-name, not ::A
    struct ::A m_a2; // OK
};
```

Note that GCC accepts this code, which I believe is a bug.

Comment: Any difference between `struct A m_a` and `A m_a`, as far as matching to injected names ?

Comment: @BenVoigt Not really (the lookup in the first case ignores non-type-names, but that's irrelevant here); both should cause an unqualified lookup for `A`.

Comment: Back in n1187, it was observed that the Standard never says whether an *injected-class-name* can be used in an *elaborated-type-specified*.  It doesn't look like this has been clarified.  I find three DRs related to n1187 but none appear to cover this particular point.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, that's mine. The standard doesn't say that the *injected-class-name* is a *typedef-name*, so there's no reason to think that it is. (Otherwise `struct Node { struct Node* Next; };` will be ill-formed, unless you introduce a separate rule that ignores *injected-class-name*s when looking up names in *elaborated-type-specifier*s.)

Comment: @T.C. But the word `first` still needs further clarification in the context of §3.3.2/7. For example, I believe that the word doesn't refer only to the scope of the class (struct in this particular example), but all the way up to the global scope. Consider this case:  `struct A; void f() { struct A* Next; }`. According to my reasoning the *elaborated-type-specifier* `struct A` in the declaration `struct A* Next;` would still NOT be the first, as a lookup for the name `Next` started in this declaration would find it in the global scope. Is that correct?

Comment: @Belloc When the *elaborated-type-specifier* is a declaration is fully specified in [basic.lookup.elab] - it is one only when name lookup fail to find a previously declared *type-name*.

Comment: @T.C. Maybe I didn't make myself clear. Consider the example:`struct A; void f() { struct A* Next; }`. Is the elaborated-type-specifier `struct A` in the declaration `struct A* Next;`, considered to be the **first** or not, in the context of §3.3.2/7?

Comment: @T.C. That is, I'm trying to understand the meaning of the word **first** in this sentence in §3.3.2/7: "The point of declaration of a class first declared in an elaborated-type-specifier is as follows:"

Comment: @Belloc It's not first declared in that elaborated-type-specifier, because that elaborated-type-specifier is not a declaration.

Comment: @T.C. That doesn't make sense to me. If what you're saying is correct the second bullet point in §3.3.2/7 would never be taken into consideration.

Answer (score -1):

The passage from 3.3.2 is about declaring classes, not objects.

Your declaration `struct Node* Next` cannot possibly match "*class-key identifier*"; the latter only matches literally half of the tokens in the former.

Comment: What matches *class-key identifier* is `struct Node`, and such an *elaborated-type-specifier* can indeed declare a class, though it does not do so in this case.

Comment: @T.C. That's what I said!

Comment: @T.C. You wrote above: "..., and such an _elaborated-type-specifier_ can indeed declare a class, ...". Could you show an example where an _elaborated-type-specifier_ of the form _class-key identifier_ declares a class, that is different from the case alluded in [\[basic.scope.pdecl\]p(7.2)](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.pdecl#7.2). I'm talking specifically about the case explicitly considered by the word "otherwise" used in the same paragraph.